# Using design time repositories in MVVM Light and SimpleIOC

Tags: mvvm-light

I have started to use the latest MVVM Light toolkit v4 (NuGet preview v4.1.21, DLL v: 4.0.21.25725), which implements the SimpleIOC pattern.

In my ViewModelLocator.cs, I have the following to handle both design and runtime repositories:

```
public ViewModelLocator()
{
  ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => SimpleIoc.Default);
  if (ViewModelBase.IsInDesignModeStatic)
  {
    SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IWebRepository, DesignWebRepository>();
  }
  else
  {
    SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IWebRepository, WebRepository>();
  }

  SimpleIoc.Default.Register<MainViewModel>();
}

public MainViewModel Main
{
  get
  {
    return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<MainViewModel>();
  }
}
```

But this gives me the following Exception *in the designer* (so no compile errors, nor runtime errors, but I loose my Blendability) for the View:
`Class Repository.IWebRepository is already registered`
(at the first .Register() call)

IWebRepository:

```
public interface IWebRepository
{
  string Test(string data);
}
```

DesignWebRepository:

```
public class DesignWebRepository : IWebRepository
{
  public string Test(string data)
  {
    return "design result: " + data;
  }
}
```

WebRepository:

```
public class WebRepository : IWebRepository
{
  public string Test(string data)
  {
    return "result: " + data;
  }
}
```

MainViewModel:

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
  IWebRepository webRepository;

  public MainViewModel(IWebRepository webRepository)
  {
    this.webRepository = webRepository;
    if (IsInDesignMode)
    {
      // Code runs in Blend --> create design time data.
    }
    else
    {
      // Code runs "for real"
    }
  }
}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: The code looks fine.  Is this MVVM Light 4?  I think you need to show your class and interface definitions.

Comment: Your code works ok for me.  I have MVVM Light v4.0.30319.  By the way, I like your SO gadget.  Shame it doesn't show responses.

Comment: Hmm.. I'm using the latest preview (4.1.21, but DLL GalaSoft.MvvmLight.WPF4.dll says v4.0.21.25725) from NuGet

Comment: Thanks, I would have thought that nobody uses Vista/Win7 desktop gadgets any more. Maybe I'll have to update it...

Comment: Whoops, I was reporting the .NET version there.  I've updated to 4.1.21 anyway - still works fine.  Try creating a new test app and paste in your code above.

Comment: I also have this issue in WP4 with 4.1.22.3 (the assemblies must be mismarked, because they say 4.*0*.22.37318).

Answer (score 0):

```
        if (ViewModelBase.IsInDesignModeStatic)
        {
            if (!SimpleIoc.Default.IsRegistered<IRepository>())
            {
                SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IRepository, DesignWebRepository>();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IRepository, WebRepository>();
        }
```

Notice the check for if the repository is already registered to prevent double registration.  Hope this fixes your problem